# $: $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors tag$

Tags: javascript, html, r, shiny

I am unable to use tags$ operator in R shiny. For any tag i am getting the error:

> $: $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors

Here is the sample app

```
server <- function(input, output, session) {

}

ui <- basicPage(
h1("Title without tags$"),
tags$blockquote("But block quote requires tags$ because it is less common than h3, h1 or code"),
h3("H3 is fine without tags and so is code here"),
code("data.frame(a=1:10, b=1:10)")
)

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Here is the error detail

```
Listening on http://127.0.0.1:3380
Warning: Error in $: $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors
Stack trace (innermost first):
49: tag
48: tags$div
47: div
46: tagList
45: attachDependencies
44: bootstrapPage
43: basicPage
 1: runApp
Error : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors
```

I am getting the same error for any tag$ operator. I am new to R shiny. Please let me know what i am missing?

Comment: Does typing `tags$a()` into the console work? What version of `shiny` are you using?

Comment: Your example works fine for me..

Comment: I think you probably defined `tags` somewhere, so it's overriding shiny::tags. Try clearing your environment

Comment: Thank you. cleaning the environment does solve the problem.